# Difference between new Message() vs Message.obtain(...) in UnitTest

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, android-handler

I am writing UnitTest for method that gets Handler as parameter, do some work and at the end use android.os.Message like following:

```
Message m = Message.obtain(handler, code, payload)
m.sendToTarget()
```

This code works as intended in runtime, but when running in unit test, it throws NullPointerException when sendToTarget is called.

If I create message with available public (but by Javadoc not recommended) constructor like:

```
Message m = new Message();
m.setTarget(handler);
m.what = code;
m.obj = payload;
```

everything works as expected without NullPointerException.

What is wrong with static factory method `Message.obtain(...)` in unit tests? Is there something that I should do differently to be able to use recommended way to get Message from the pool instead of making new one.